# Retornar resultado <andrebaill> no navegador

Tags: html

Tenho a seguinte resposta:

```
<<?php echo $valor->usu_id; ?>>
```

Porém, é interpretado pelo navegador como TAG e não como retorno. 
Como eu faço para ele retornar sem ser tag? Neste exemplo, retornaria `<andrebaill>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use entidades HTML, assim:

```
&lt;<?php echo $valor->usu_id; ?>&gt;
```

Um exemplo em HTML puro:

```html
Vira tag: <br>

<foobar>

<hr>

É "visivel": <br>

&lt;foobar&gt;
```

Lista de entidades HTML no site w3.org: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Se o conteudo vier de uma variável no PHP (ou banco) você pode usar `htmlspecialchars` assim:

```
<?php $foobar = '<foobar>'; ?>

<?php echo htmlspecialchars($foobar); ?>
```

> **Nota:**
>
> A diferença de `htmlspecialchars` e `htmlentities` é que o `htmlspecialchars` só codifica caracteres que tem algum significado para o HTML, já o `htmlentities` codifica tudo que tem o equivalente em *"entidades HTML"*

---

Note que existe a tag `<xmp>` também que poderá ter o mesmo efeito, no entanto ela **é obsoleta** (apesar de ainda funcionar):

```html
<xmp><foobar></xmp>
```